# Access Raspberry Pi 4 system timer

Tags: embedded-linux, hardware, raspberry-pi4

I'm having trouble reading the Raspberry Pi 4 system timer.
My understanding is that the LO 32 bits should be at address 0x7e003004.
My reads always return -1.
Here's how I am trying:

```
int fd;
unsigned char* start;
uint32_t* t4lo;

fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1)
{
perror("open /dev/mem");
exit(1);
}
start = (unsigned char*)mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED,
fd, 0x7e003000);
t4lo = (unsigned int *)(start + 0x04);
...
uint32_t Rpi::readTimer(void)
{
    return *t4lo;
}
```

I should be checking the value of start, but gdb tells me it's reasonable so I don't think that's the problem.

```
(gdb) p t4lo
$4 = (uint32_t *) 0xb6f3a004
```

and gdb won't let me access *t4lo. Any ideas?

Edit: clock_gettime() is fulfilling my needs, but I'm still curious.

Comment: You probably want it to be `volatile` for starters.  But that may not be your main problem.

Comment: Good catch. But you're right, that didn't fix it.

Comment: https://www.studica.com/blog/raspberry-pi-timer-embedded-environments suggests the timer might be at `0x3f003004` instead.

Comment: That article spells out that it applies to RPi 2 or 3. Model 4 has a new processor, and things have moved. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/rpi_DATA_2711_1p0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A closer look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/rpi_DATA_2711_1p0.pdf
figure 1 on page 5 shows that addresses vary depending upon who's looking at things. If you start with 0x7c00_0000 on the left side and follow it over to the right, it's apparent that it shows up at 0xfc00_0000 to the processor. So changing the timer base address to 0xfe00_3000 fixed the problem.

The secret is hidden in section 1.2.4:

```
So a peripheral described in this document as being at legacy address 0x7Enn_nnnn
is available in the 35-bit address space at 0x4_7Enn_nnnn, and visible to the ARM
at 0x0_FEnn_nnnn if Low Peripheral mode is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

The address of the BCM2711 ARM Peripherals is the **bus address** which is not the same as the **physical address** in most systems. The bus address is easily used by DMA(Direct Memory Access) controller. **mmap** creates a new mapping from physical address to **virtual address** not bus address. So you can't use mmap funtion with parameter 0x7e003000. The **rich** answer is right.

> So changing the timer base address to 0xfe00_3000 fixed the problem.

In addtion, your program run in the **User space**, only virtual address can you directly use.